# Reactjs Event/Action Button not switching as expected

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs Event/Action Button not switching as expected.

Am trying to add **follow and unfollow** action button. when I post via **axios** via Follow button, 
it post to data to server backend and return success message. Then the Follow button switched to Unfollow button.

Now my problem is that Unfollow button is not switching back to Follow Button when User try to unfollow someone.

Please what am I doing wrong here.

**here is the json success message**

```
[{"status":"success", "follow":"1", "unfollow":"0"}]
```

**here is the my code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result_data: '',
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [{"uid":"1","name":"Nancy"},{"uid":"2","name":"Moore"}],
    });
  }

  // update user following
  handleFollowUser(user_id) {
    const uid_data = { user_id: user_id };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/data.json", { uid_data })
      .then(response => {

          this.setState(state => ({
            //data: newData,
            result_data: response.data[0].status
          }));
          alert(result_data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

// update user unfollowing 
  handleUnFollowUser(user_id) {
    const uid_data = { user_id: user_id };
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/data.json", { uid_data })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          //data: newData,
          result_data: response.data[0].status
        }));
        alert(result_data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            <h1>Users</h1> <br />
            {this.state.result_data }
            {this.state.data.map((users) => {
              return (
                <div key={users.uid}>
                  <div>
                    <b> Name: </b>{users.name} 
                    <br />
                    {this.state.result_data === '' 
                      ? <span onClick={() => 
                        this.handleFollowUser(users.uid)}>Follow</span>
                      : <span onClick={() => 
                        this.handleUnFollowUser(users.uid)}>unfollow</span>
                      }
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            }
          )}
        </ul>
      </label>
    </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: according to your logic, shouldn't you be setting `result_data` to `''` on you `handleUnFollowUser` function?

Comment: You should remove the operator and set your turnary to `!this.state.result_data` and allow result_data to be set to a boolean in order for the toggle of the buttons.

Comment: It's because you never set `result_data` to '' after component is mounted.

Comment: please can you guys provide me sample illustration of how to go about with that. between thanks for effort so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved **my Reactjs** problem.I first initialize 
`isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn` in the click event and in the constructor I implemented

```
  this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
```

My click button becomes

```
<button onClick={this.handleFollowUser}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'Follow' : 'Unfollow'}
      </button>
```